# Is there a way to declare types that only accept certain subsets of a different type?

Tags: rust

My imaginary rust code would be something like this

```
enum Foo {
    FirstThreeChars('a' | 'b' | 'c'),
    Bools(0 | 1),
}
```

Where `FirstThreeChars` accepts a subset of characters.

I seem to remember Haskell having something like this but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Put data inside the enum variant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html):

```
enum MyChars {
   A,
   B,
   C
}

enum Foo {
  FirstThreeChars(MyChars) // custom type to allow only subset of characters
  Bools(bool)   // native boolean type
}
```